# caching images in android

Tags: android, caching

I want to cache some images when downloaded and when again my application starts, it should check if the images are cached so it returns images otherwise null , so I download and cache them again

I tried using LRU Cache http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html but it didn't work for me , coz its for API level 12, and I am working on 10.
here is that question
[caching images with LruCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716214/caching-images-with-lrucache)

What are the other easy adoptable possible solutions to cache

Comment: I download to phones memory and check before downloading if the file exists!

Comment: @Alborz how does it work

Comment: @Alborz and I both do it the same way it seems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay I did like this

```
        private Bitmap getFile(String fileName) {
        Bitmap file = null;
         try {
              FileInputStream fis; 
              fis = openFileInput(fileName);
              file = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

              fis.close();
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return file;
    }
    protected void putFile(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName){
        FileOutputStream fos;
           try {
            fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
           }    
           catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        for (int i = 0; i < HomeActivity.globalObj.categoriesList.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap b;
            b = getFile(HomeActivity.globalObj.categoriesList.get(i).name);
            if (b == null) {
                b = getImageBitmap(HomeActivity.globalObj.categoriesList.get(i).large_image);
                putFile(b, HomeActivity.globalObj.categoriesList.get(i).name);

            }
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            iv.setImageBitmap(b);
            imageViewList.add(iv);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this for storing your files:
[Storage options android sdk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Read it, try, and ask question if not successful. That's the best way to learn, instead of copy someone elses code. (and we are talking external storage here).